# What are all the Ubuntu one letter commands?

Tags: command-line

I came across this command whilst setting up `ssh`:

```bash
$ w

 20:01:30 up 6 days,  2:20,  3 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.11, 0.10
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
rick     tty7     :0               16Jun20  6days 16:51   2.37s /sbin/upstart --user
rick     pts/21   192.168.0.12     18:44    1:14m  0.19s  0.00s sleep 60
rick     pts/22   192.168.0.12     18:45    0.00s  0.44s  0.01s w
```

Which led me to wonder what all the one letter commands are in Ubuntu. I didn't find an exact reference but I found this website:

- [An A-Z Index of the Linux command line: bash + utilities.](https://ss64.com/bash/)

Here the `w` command is listed along with:

- `.` the command to source a file which I've used
- `v` is a command not installed in Ubuntu. It is said to be equivalent to `ls -l -b`. This in turn is similar to the the `ll` alias setup by Ubuntu except files beginning with `.` (including the infamous `.` and `..`) are not included.

Are there other one letter commands installed within Ubuntu by default?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*TL;DR*: This tells you about each command whose name is a single character, though you may want to simplify or otherwise adjust it:

```bsh
(set -f; type -a $(compgen -cX '!?' | sort -u))
```

### Listing one-character commands with `compgen`

Bash has tab completion and offers a `compgen` builtin, which provides insight into how text is completed. By running `compgen -c`, you can list *all* the commands on your system. So one way to list all commands that are just one character long is to filter the output of `compgen -c`:

```bsh
compgen -c | grep '^.$'
```

**As [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) has [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252962/what-are-all-the-ubuntu-one-letter-commands/1253013#comment2116017_1253013)**, `compgen` accepts an `-X` option to do its own filtering. Somewhat nonintuitively, the operand to `-X` is a pattern whose matches are *removed*. It supports globbing syntax that works like filename expansion, but also supports an initial `!` to negate it, achieving the desired effect here. (See [Programmable Completion Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) for more information about the syntax.) `?` matches any single character, so `!?` matches anything that is not a single character, so `-X '!?'` removes everything that is not a single character, leaving only single-character commands:

```bsh
compgen -cX '!?'
```

That shows the same results, in the same order, as piping to `grep`. You can pass `-c` and `-X` in one argument as `-cX` or (as [steeldriver shows it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252962/what-are-all-the-ubuntu-one-letter-commands/1253013#comment2116017_1253013)) in two arguments as `-c -X`.

On my system, I get:

```
l
p
{
}
!
.
:
[
s
t
[
X
w
```

`s` and `t` on my system are scripts I wrote; you most likely don't have commands with those names. You likely do have the others.

Whether these are all really *commands* or not depends on what one thinks of as a command. `{`, `}`, and `!` are *shell keywords*, like `if`, `case`, `while`, and `for`. The others (including shell builtins) are unambiguously commands in the usual sense.

### The meaning of repeated results

Some commands, such as `[` in the above output, may be repeated. This happens when more than one command of the same name exists. Bash offers `[` as a shell builtin, but it is also an executable located in `/usr/bin`. Running `type cmd` shows what type of command *`cmd`* is and, if it is an external command, where it is located. When there is more than one command of the same name, it shows the one that will actually be used. **As [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy) has [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252962/what-are-all-the-ubuntu-one-letter-commands/1253013#comment2115994_1253013)**, you can see them all using `type -a cmd`.

```bsh
$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[
```

There's another source of possible duplication: on some systems, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are actually the same directory (more precisely: `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`) and you'll see entries in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. For example, you may have both `/bin/[` and `/usr/bin/[` as well as the `[` builtin, as well as both `/bin/w` and `/usr/bin/w` and both `/bin/X` and `/usr/bin/X`. These are technically separate commands, but they actually refer to the *same* executable.

Traditionally, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` were separate directories (so that commands in `/bin` would be usable even when `/usr` is an NFS volume that is not yet mounted). But these days this doesn't usually offer a benefit. So newer systems tend to unify them. If you're using a newer release, you probably have this, *unless you upgraded to it from an older release that did not*.

If you like, you can sort the output of `compgen` and remove duplicates:

```bsh
compgen -c | grep '^.$' | sort -u
```

```bsh
compgen -cX '!?' | sort -u
```

### Showing details on all the commands

For more detail, you might wish to know what type of command each one is and:

- for the external commands, where they are located.
- for aliases and shell functions, how they are defined.

As mentioned above, Bash's `type` builtin will tell you all this. You can write a command that supplies the filtered output of `compgen` to `type`.

```bsh
type $(compgen -c | grep '^.$')
```

```bsh
type $(compgen -cX '!?')
```

That will behave badly if you have a `*` or `?` command. That's quite unlikely, but not impossible. To safeguard against that, you may want to disable globbing:

```bsh
(set -f; type $(compgen -c | grep '^.$'))
```

```bsh
(set -f; type $(compgen -cX '!?'))
```

But this (with any of those four alternatives) is imperfect, because all commands of the same name have the same explanation, which is only correct for the first one. For example, on my system, I get:

```
l is aliased to `ls -CF'
p is aliased to `printf "\e[?2004l"'
{ is a shell keyword
} is a shell keyword
! is a shell keyword
. is a shell builtin
: is a shell builtin
[ is a shell builtin
s is /home/ek/bin/s
t is /home/ek/bin/t
[ is a shell builtin
X is /usr/bin/X
w is /usr/bin/w
```

You may very well only want to see information about the first occurrence of each command of the same name (e.g., the shell builtin `[`). After all, **those are the ones that actually run, when you write a command whose first word is any of those one-character names** (e.g., `[ -f /bin/nano ]` runs the shell builtin `[`, not `/usr/bin/[`). If so, you can sort the output of `compgen` and remove duplicates before handing the results to `type`:

```bsh
type $(compgen -c | grep '^.$' | sort -u)
```

```bsh
type $(compgen -cX '!?' | sort -u)
```

Or, to also safeguard against globbing:

```bsh
(set -f; type $(compgen -c | grep '^.$' | sort -u))
```

```bsh
(set -f; type $(compgen -cX '!?' | sort -u))
```

However, if you want information about all the commands (e.g., `/usr/bin/[` as well as `[`), then you can pass `-a` to `type`. I recommend that you still sort and remove duplicates from the results first, or you'll get lots of repetition in the output.

```bsh
type -a $(compgen -c | grep '^.$' | sort -u)
```

```bsh
type -a $(compgen -cX '!?' | sort -u)
```

Or, to also safeguard against globbing:

```bsh
(set -f; type -a $(compgen -c | grep '^.$' | sort -u))
```

```bsh
(set -f; type -a $(compgen -cX '!?' | sort -u))
```

### What commands you have varies across shell environments

Note that which one-character commands you have, like which commands you have in general, is a property of your shell environment. Different users, or different running shells by the same user, may have different commands available. The `l` command in Ubuntu, for example, is defined in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, which is copied to `~/.bashrc` when user accounts are created in the usual way.

```bsh
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

You can thus change or remove the definition of `l` in your per-user `~/.bashrc`. Or simply run `unalias l` to affect just your current shell.

Comment: I think it'll be better to use `-a` option with `type` since `[ is a shell builtin`, `[ is /usr/bin/[`
and `[ is /bin/[` (at least in my system).

Comment: I was playing with this last night and came up with `compgen -c -X '!?'` (using compgen's built-in pattern matching / pattern exclusion feature as an alternative to using `grep`)